# When porting Qt4 to QT5, it prompts that #include<QX11Info> cannot be found

Tags: qt5, qt4

When porting Qt4 to QT5, it prompts that #include cannot be found
I have QX11Info under Qtx11Extras, but it reported #include not found.
I want to reference the code written in qt4 as a library in my qt5 code after running it
Has anyone encountered similar problems? Please give me some solutions

Comment: Did you add `QT += x11extras` to your `.pro` file (assuming you're using `qmake`)?

Comment: I am using VsCode not QtCreator, there is no .pro file(
not using qmake)